# Change and Show max_allowed_packet of "client side" by MySQL command

Tags: mysql, database

I totally understand there are bunch of questions about how to set and show *max_allowed_packet* value.

> SET: SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = numeric
>
> SHOW: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';

But this variable is *max_allowed_packet* on **server side**.

As mentioned in [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html):

> Both **the client and the server** have their own max_allowed_packet
> variable, so if you want to handle big packets, you must increase this
> variable both in the client and in the server.

Can I set and show the **client side** *max_allowed_packet* by MySQL command like "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE XXX"?

Start mysql with this option can work.

> shell> mysql --max_allowed_packet=32M

But I am looking for the command line.

Comment: No. The server cannot force the client to increase that value, which basically defines how much buffer memory the client wants to use (e.g. because the client might not have sufficient memory). It's actually a bit unfortunate that the two different values for "how much do I want to send" and "how much can I retrieve" have the same name.

Comment: Actually the reason why I care about it is because I am trying to optimize the "number of insert per query" to improve the performance. But I am worried that if the packet exceeds "client side max_allowed_packet", it may fail and close the connection.

Comment: My plan is, dynamically setting "number of insert per query" and depends on the max_allowed_packet which retrieved from  "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';" during run time.
Is it conventional or any better idea?

Comment: a) Your client setting doesn't reflect what you can send, just what you can receive, so for your inserts, you can use the variable the server tells you b) while a single insert is indeed slow and adding more increases throughput (rows/s), this will reach a peak (and adding *too many* rows can actually slow it down again). The peak may vary, but expect it to be more in the area of 500 than the area of 10k. With "normal" row sizes, that will usually not conflict with max_allowed_packet, and with larger row sizes, the peak will decrease (although not fast enough to *never* generate a conflict).

Answer (score 1):

```
Ubuntu 18.04 and mysql 5.7.29

1) vi /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
# make the following change:
max_allowed_packet = 1G

2) service mysql restart

3) sudo mysql -u <username> -p

4) mysql> show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
```

Comment: While these commands may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This looks a heck of a lot like it's setting the **server-side** max packet size, which is explicitly _not_ what the question is about.